# Does muscle growth trigger angiogenesis?

Tags: human-biology

So heavier people generally have more blood than lighter people (this is why heavier people generally need to take higher doses of medication for the same effect of medication). They also have more blood to draw from. But this fails to differentiate between muscle mass and fat mass.

So here's my question: Is the net angiogenesis per gram of muscle more or less than the net angiogenesis per gram of fat?

Comment: Without having an exact proof, I'd definitely say yes. Muscles need more nutriments to function than fat, and if you look at the body builders you'll see that some those guys have thicker brachial veins than an average aorta.

Comment: See [this article](http://ceaccp.oxfordjournals.org/content/4/5/152.full) as to why your underlying assumption is incorrect.  Higher doses must be given due to the high fat solubility of some drugs as well as differences in liver and kidney size.

Comment: Oh wow - thanks for that information. Doesn't that mean that for those with high muscle mass (relative to fat mass), that the guidelines for how much drug they take might be inaccurate?

Comment: Specific doses are usually not calculated as several factors may dictate upgrading the dose, not only weight or fat content. Drug sensitivity can be caused by the speed at which the liver removes the drug from the blood or genetic factors that make the drug more effective or the severity of the condition for instance.  Weight is just one factor that will increase the dose, all other factors being equal.

Answer (score 1):

Muscle is heavier than fat so actually it does. Muscle growth directly increases angiogenesis. Particularly the mechanism relies on hypoxia, any tissue with less than adequate blood supply secretes factors which result in angiogenesis. This is seen frequently when muscle is bulking as this increases the oxygen requirement but is also seen in heart muscle where subsequent to a heart attack tissue which isn't dead but mildly suffering caused new blood vessels to grow to supply this tissue (as the other ones are blocked which was the cause of the heart attack in most cases).